# aiohttp - how to know when i request client is disconnected?

Tags: python, aiohttp

```py
    async def index(self,request):
        content = open(os.path.join(self.ROOT, "index.html"), encoding="utf8").read()
        while(True):
            time.sleep(1)
            #if request.transport["status"] == "disconnected":
            #   break
            ...
            ...
```

How to know when a client is disconnected in an aiohttp request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In aiohttp, you can check whether the client is disconnected by monitoring the request.transport object. The request.transport object represents the transport layer (TCP, SSL, etc.) associated with the current request.

```
from aiohttp import web

class YourView(web.View):
    async def index(self, request):
        content = open(os.path.join(self.ROOT, "index.html"), encoding="utf8").read()

        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

            # Check if the transport is closed/disconnected
            if request.transport is None or request.transport.is_closing():
                break

            # Your other logic here...

        # Any cleanup or finalization logic after the loop
        ...

        return web.Response(text="Done")
```